# как в vue.js создать плагин отдельным файлом?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Можно ли создать плагин в отдельном файле? Есть вариант создать js файл и просто подключить его. Но правильно ли так делать? Может можно как-то более правильно? Как, например, компоненты можно выносить в отдельные файлы

Comment: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Создание-плагина

Answer (score 0):

Я бы на вашем месте посмотрел как делают другие. Например, взял несколько библиотек компонентов, которые построены на vue:

1. https://github.com/rafaelpimpa/buefy
2. https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material
3. ...

И посмотрел как реализована модульность, объединение и т.д.